# Code coverage from running this test class was not applied due to a conflicting recompilation task running at the same time

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package

Did anyone had faced this issue? Is there a solution?

I'm not sure if this is a bug or what else can I do to view the code coverage in a Package Org (Classic Managed Package).

When I try to run all the tests in a Managed Package org I see the error "Code coverage from running this test class was not applied due to a conflicting recompilation task running at the same time" in many tests even after recompiling all apex classes.

Comment: Have you tried running the tests again, at a time when there isn't a re-compilation taking place?

Comment: Yes, tried again. It seems that only worked if I run them separately, which makes me feel this is a bug.

Comment: @JefersonChaves Please update here if you find any resolution. I am also facing the same issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of conflicts coming from parallel execution of multiple test runs. You can try disabling the 'Parallel Apex Testing' setting under Apex Test Execution settings.

Steps to follow:
Setup | Apex Test Execution | Option | Disable Parallel Apex Testing - True

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, the package org I tried this, as far as I recall had parallel testing disabled. Did this solved the problem for you?

Comment: Yes Jef, it did.